# Content type of the response currently being executed in PHP?

Tags: php, content-type

Let's say there is a library function that needs to know the exact MIME type of the HTTP response currently being generated by a PHP script, regardless of whether it was explicitly set via `header('Content-type: ...')` or not. Also, if possible, regardless of whether output has actually started or not (I doubt this one, but...).

It could be, for example, a function that outputs diagnostics/debug information and wants to format its output depending on whether current content type is HTML, XML, or plain text.

A script is aware if it's running from the command line (`php_sapi_name() == 'cli'`) and thus content type can be assumed `text/plain`, however, any way to accurately detect it when run under the server?

Answer (score 1):

By default the `Content-type` of the output from PHP will be `text/html` when not running on the cli.  As you already know, when running from a cli the output is `text/plain`.

There is a function [headers_list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) that will tell you the headers that will be sent (or have been sent).  You can possibly leverage that to determine what the `Content-type` will be. I've never used it; I just know it exists.

Comment: Thanks Levi... headers_list() though doesnn't list Content-type before output is started (naturally).